# PDFsharp - draw text, rotate it around a custom pivot point and move it

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I would like to draw a text which is rotated around x degrees. Due to the fact I don't rotate it around it's center point I want to provide an offset too.

First I rotate the rectangle around the custom pivot point

```
graphics.RotateAtTransform(RotationInDegrees, pivotPoint);
```

and I know I can move the transform with

```
graphics.TranslateTransform(offsetX, offsetY);
```

but to calculate the offset I need to know the new directions, so top might be bottom now on 180 degrees.

I have a 2D vector representing a grid system where center is at (0|0), top left (-1|1), bottom right (1|-1) etc. So basically I could rotate first, then draw the text

```
textFormatter.DrawString(watermarkContent, Font, Brush, textBox, Format);
```

and after drawing the textBox I translate it. Then I could use this calculation to know the correct rotation

```
graphics.TranslateTransform(alignmentVector.X * -horizontalOffset, alignmentVector.Y * verticalOffset);
```

but this is not possible. I have to apply the transformations first and draw at the end. So how can I apply the horizontal and vertical offset to the rectangle correctly (by knowing the correct direction) after rotating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformations apply to items that get drawn after setting the transformations. This allows to draw text at a 30° angle and other text at a 60° angle by changing the transformations later on.

So you have to apply the transformations before drawing the text. The transformation also applies to the "textbox" used to draw the text and there is no need to change that box.

Also see this sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx

Comment: Thanks, but after rotating the textbox around a custom pivot point I want to move it by an offset. But this requires me to know the rotated textbox I think ...

Comment: You rotate and move the XGraphics object around - and the textbox moves around with the XGraphics object as it just specifies the width and the height of the drawing area. Check the sample linked above and other PDFsharp samples that use transformations.

Comment: I updated my question and hope this makes some things more clear

Comment: Maybe it is simpler to apply the offset first, then the rotation (apply offset to pivot point), then draw the text (without caring about any transformations, just draw the text).